# TextView intercepting touch events while scrolling in ViewPager

Tags: android

There's a `TextView` inside a `ViewPager`, when the `ViewPager` is scrolled from a portion near `TextView` the scroll event is intercepted by `TextView` itself.

This `TextView` is in relative layout of fragment in `ViewPager`

<TextView

```
                android:id="@+id/tv_course_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Example Course"
                android:singleline="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some more information about the issue you are running into. The community can only help you if you can provide the full relevant code and describe both the expected behaviour and the behaviour you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `android:singleLine="true"` with `android:maxLines="1"`

Happy Coding.

Comment: what do you understand from the question ? Can you explain ?

Comment: @NJ I think he's facing a problem where there's a textview inside a view pager, when the view pager is scrolled from a portion near  textview the scroll event is intercepted by textview itself, I had faced this problem before.

Comment: Edit his question and add the information that you wrote in a comment.  So the future user will get the clue about the question. Currently, question is not understandable.